# convert excel cell text into number poi

Tags: java, export-to-excel, apache-poi

HAI

i want ot convert a cell text value into a number in Excel using POI API.

cell text value like '2,345' to conver as a number.

How can i do that.

if any has face this problem,please let me know...

Answer (score 6):

In case you have the value stored as a String, use:

```
String valueAsString = "2345";
cell.setCellValue(new BigDecimal(valueAsString).doubleValue());
```

If your value is a number, pass it to the method directly:

```
cell.setCellValue(2345);
```